# Can I add netlify environment variables to my Angular app?

Tags: angular, netlify, dotenv

Angular has its own environment folder which has **environment.ts** and **environment.prod.ts**. I'm trying to host my Angular app but hide my api key in netlify, netlify has a nice environment variable feature where you place you api key with a name that you want, but how do I add this variable to my Angular app?

environment.prod.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  googleMapsApi: GOOGLE_NETLIFY
  ,
};
```

GOOGLE_NETLIFY is saved in my netlify deploy settings. Maybe I need to add this **netlify.toml** file but I can't find the right information for Angular and adding netlify variables with this.

Comment: `process.env.GOOGLE_NETLIFY`?

Comment: I guess you need to create environment.ts "on the fly" in the netifly build, but before step where you are building the angular app. When you create env file you take a proper env variable to set the value, so you could have a different API key for each environment.